How to make css infinite animation slider work on mobile?
I am creating a price ticker/slider, it works perfectly on desktop/laptop but I can't get it to work correctly on mobile without glitching.
On mobile, the ticker items just appear for a few seconds then they disappear without any sliding animation.
Imgur Clip of bug: Clip
Snippet below also.
EDIT - If I remove the display-flex from the .ticker-container it works good but the ticker items go outside the div so the slider resets before showing all ticker items..
Here is an example of what I have so far:


const tickerMap = {
  'bitcoin': 'BTC',
  'ethereum': 'ETH',
  'binancecoin': 'BNB',
  'bitcoin-cash': 'BCH',
  'litecoin': 'LTC',
  'ripple': 'XRP',
  'chainlink': 'LINK',
  'matic-network': 'MATIC',
  'cardano': 'ADA',
  'dogecoin': 'DOGE',
  'shiba-inu': 'SHIB',
  'solana': 'SOL',
  'pepe': 'PEPE',
  'avalanche-2': 'AVAX',
  'polkadot': 'DOT'
};


async function fetchCryptoPrices() {
  try {
const response = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin,ethereum,ripple,solana,pepe,binancecoin,avalanche-2,chainlink,matic-network,bitcoin-cash,shiba-inu,litecoin,polkadot,cardano,dogecoin&vs_currencies=usd', {
  mode: "cors"
});

  //const responseData = '{"avalanche-2":{"usd":44.41},"binancecoin":{"usd":577.56},"bitcoin":{"usd":66572},"bitcoin-cash":{"usd":679.98},"cardano":{"usd":0.565032},"chainlink":{"usd":17.01},"dogecoin":{"usd":0.16979},"ethereum":{"usd":3239.5},"litecoin":{"usd":96.28},"matic-network":{"usd":0.867247},"pepe":{"usd":6.44e-06},"polkadot":{"usd":8.16},"ripple":{"usd":0.573485},"shiba-inu":{"usd":2.662e-05},"solana":{"usd":170.15}}'

   const responseData = await response.text();
    console.log('Response from server:', responseData);
   const data = JSON.parse(responseData);
  return data;
 } catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching cryptocurrency prices:', error);
   return null;
 }
}

 async function createTickerItems() {
 const ticker = document.getElementById('ticker');
 ticker.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous ticker items
 const cryptoPrices = await fetchCryptoPrices();
 if (cryptoPrices) {
  Object.entries(cryptoPrices).forEach(([symbol, price]) => {
  const tickerItem = document.createElement('div');
  tickerItem.classList.add('ticker-item');
  // Get the ticker symbol from the mapping, defaulting to the full name if not found
  const tickerSymbol = tickerMap[symbol] || symbol.toUpperCase();
  // Check if the symbol is one that needs custom decimal places
  let formattedPrice;
  if (symbol === 'shiba-inu' || symbol === 'pepe') {
    // Format price for custom decimal places
    formattedPrice = `$${price.usd.toFixed(6)}`;
  } else {
    // Default formatting for other tokens
    formattedPrice = `$${price.usd.toFixed(2)}`;
  }
  tickerItem.textContent = `${tickerSymbol}: ${formattedPrice}`;
  ticker.appendChild(tickerItem);
  });
  }
 }
// Initialize ticker
createTickerItems();
    .ticker-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #111113;
  border-top: 1px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ticker {
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
  width: max-content;
}

.ticker-item {
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #1a191f;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ticker-item:last-of-type {
  background-color: blue;
}

.ticker-item:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform:
  }
  100% {}
  from {
    transform: translateX(100dvw);
    /* Use 100% of the viewport, not 100% of the element -> avoid waiting to long if you have many elements */
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@media(max-width:998px) {
  .ticker {
    animation: marquee 20s linear infinite !important;
  }
  .ticker-item {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
  }
}
<div class="ticker-container">
  <div class="ticker" id="ticker">
    <!-- Ticker items will be inserted here dynamically -->
  </div>
</div>




Cannot reproduce on my mobile. Try clearing/refreshing your cache

@SioGabx Hmm, yeah appears to be working in Chrome on mobile, Guess it's just an issue with Safari.. EDIT - I changed animation to 20s to slow it down and now it has the same bug again even in Chrome on mobile lol

If by removing display-flex it works, you can try this code where a used display:inline-block; and width: max-content; to have the size of it's content to be able to show everything.


const tickerMap = {
  'bitcoin': 'BTC',
  'ethereum': 'ETH',
  'binancecoin': 'BNB',
  'bitcoin-cash': 'BCH',
  'litecoin': 'LTC',
  'ripple': 'XRP',
  'chainlink': 'LINK',
  'matic-network': 'MATIC',
  'cardano': 'ADA',
  'dogecoin': 'DOGE',
  'shiba-inu': 'SHIB',
  'solana': 'SOL',
  'pepe': 'PEPE',
  'avalanche-2': 'AVAX',
  'polkadot': 'DOT'
};


async function fetchCryptoPrices() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin,ethereum,ripple,solana,pepe,binancecoin,avalanche-2,chainlink,matic-network,bitcoin-cash,shiba-inu,litecoin,polkadot,cardano,dogecoin&vs_currencies=usd', {
      mode: "cors"
    });

    //const responseData = '{"avalanche-2":{"usd":44.41},"binancecoin":{"usd":577.56},"bitcoin":{"usd":66572},"bitcoin-cash":{"usd":679.98},"cardano":{"usd":0.565032},"chainlink":{"usd":17.01},"dogecoin":{"usd":0.16979},"ethereum":{"usd":3239.5},"litecoin":{"usd":96.28},"matic-network":{"usd":0.867247},"pepe":{"usd":6.44e-06},"polkadot":{"usd":8.16},"ripple":{"usd":0.573485},"shiba-inu":{"usd":2.662e-05},"solana":{"usd":170.15}}'

    const responseData = await response.text();
    console.log('Response from server:', responseData);
    const data = JSON.parse(responseData);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching cryptocurrency prices:', error);
    return null;
  }
}

async function createTickerItems() {
  const cryptoPrices = await fetchCryptoPrices();
  if (cryptoPrices) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".ticker-item").forEach((element) => element.remove()); // Clear previous ticker items
    Object.entries(cryptoPrices).forEach(([symbol, price]) => {
      const tickerItem = document.createElement('div');
      tickerItem.classList.add('ticker-item');
      // Get the ticker symbol from the mapping, defaulting to the full name if not found
      const tickerSymbol = tickerMap[symbol] || symbol.toUpperCase();
      // Check if the symbol is one that needs custom decimal places
      let formattedPrice;
      if (symbol === 'shiba-inu' || symbol === 'pepe') {
        // Format price for custom decimal places
        formattedPrice = `$${price.usd.toFixed(6)}`;
      } else {
        // Default formatting for other tokens
        formattedPrice = `$${price.usd.toFixed(2)}`;
      }
      tickerItem.textContent = `${tickerSymbol}: ${formattedPrice}`;

      const ticker = document.getElementById('ticker');
      ticker.appendChild(tickerItem);
    });
  }
}
// Initialize ticker
createTickerItems();
.ticker-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #111113;
  border-top: 1px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ticker {
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
  width: max-content;
}

.ticker-item {
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #1a191f;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ticker-item:last-of-type {
  background-color: blue;
}

.ticker-item:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform:
  }
  100% {}
  from {
    transform: translateX(100dvw);
    /* Use 100% of the viewport, not 100% of the element -> avoid waiting to long if you have many elements */
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@media(max-width:998px) {
  .ticker {
    animation: marquee 20s linear infinite !important;
  }
  .ticker-item {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
  }
}
<div class="ticker-container">
  <div class="ticker" id="ticker">
    <!-- Ticker items will be inserted here dynamically -->
  </div>
</div>




Thanks, but unfortunately when I refresh page on mobile it only shows 1 ticker item before resetting back to the start again, it's weird because if I close mobile browser app without fully closing the app (swiping it away) and I re-open the app it shows it working

I cannot reproduce your issue again... do you perform the test with only the code I sent you?

Its weird because I copy all your code separatly like first the css, then the html, then the JS and now it is working thankyou, but I dont understand what part changed, was it the JS? thanks

I got it working with your code, but I can't get it working with the original url (api) for some reason. EDIT - No worries I got it, forgot to do async for the second function, thanks for your help! It's working really well on both desktop/laptop and mobile now (and I assume its probably fine on tablet too) Thanks!

Ignore my previous comment, I can't get it working with the url anymore, it keeps breaking every time I change it to async and when I change the url to the api

@DaTZcodie I added back the javascript with the api, can you recheck with this one ?

That seems a lot better, but sometimes when I refresh the page it moves slow and resets after one ticker item, I think it might be some kind of weird timing issue, but this is definitely a big improvement so thanks I appreciate this a lot :)

I added a short clip to the question incase you wanted to see exactly what's happening :)

I have moved ticker.innerHTML to only clear when we have data, can you try ?

Hmm that actually seems to cause the bug to happen every time/refresh :'))

I have the impression that the browser executes appendChild before applying innerHTML.  Maybe this can be fixed by using remove instead, can you try (answer updated) ?

Unfortunately the issue remains, I've temporarily put the code onto this spare domain: https://coindrops.xyz, is the bug showing on your end if you access it on your mobile?

No, it works perfectly (I use Chrome on Android by the way)

Damn, I use iPhone, guess it's some issue with iOS then, I can't get it to work properly on Safari or Chrome on iPhone lol
